# Anything to prevent apps from moving around monitors when unplugged?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

When I do anything on my PC there is a chance that the cable on my second monitor comes loose, but that's a problem when I play games because even if it's only a second it causes both of my monitors to flash black screen for few seconds and than all apps move to main monitor that didn't unplug.

Is there any tool that stops from app windows moving and changing both monitor settings when one monitor is unplugged? If I don't use my second monitor I don't put apps there or I disable it in nvidia panel.

But when my second monitor cable loses connection for second and both screens go black for 5seconds it's not fun when you're playing games and suddenly you can't see or maybe even do anything for few moments that could be criticaly imoportant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No.

Windows (or any other OS) is going to automatically resize the desktop and try to move everything to a connected screen when it detects a change to the monitor configuration. This is for your benefit, not detriment.

The flashing to black occurs because the display adapter is being reset and reconfigured to support the new monitor configuration.

You're not going to be able to fix this for running applications/games.

For desktop icons, you can use the application [Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/), which lets you setup zones of icons that never move from where you put them. At least the icons will stay in the same place when the desktop resizes for any reason.

I think the real question/answer is stopping your monitor cables from being inadvertently disconnected, not software to work around that problem. Cables being disconnected seems odd. All display cables have a holding mechanism to keep the cable in place: VGA/DVI cables have screws, HDMI is pressure fit, and DisplayPort is pressure fit with hooked pins. They should never come out without some effort.

Maybe the cables are stretched too far and putting strain on the connectors. Maybe you are banging your desk so hard when losing in Call of Duty that you disconnect your monitors.

Regardless of the reason, you need to fix your setup so the cables don't become disconnected.

Comment: My second monitor is connected through HDMI to VGA reduction, the HDMI connector is like 1mm less longer than other HDMI cable I have, I'll try diffrent types of plugging with the HDMI cable if I'm putting it too far in, also I noticed that the HDMI side gets pretty hot almost hard to hold...

Comment: Hot HDMI cables could be a sign of an issue with the cable or transmitting device. Although, the digital to analog signal conversion of your VGA adapter may be contributing to that. Typically HDMI doesn't get hot on its own, unless its connected to device that is really hot (like a video card, maybe) or is getting hot air blown onto it from a device exhaust. You could try to get one of these conversion cables, with HDMI on one end and VGA on the other, and make sure it is of sufficient length to not be unplugged. Amazon Link > https://tinyurl.com/y3ajklpe