# How to switch off one of monitors but keep windows/programs stay on their current positions

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors but 2nd monitor is used for coding only. So I want to turn it off when I don't code. I often use (the Windows key + P) or the Power button. However, if I do that all windows from 2nd monitor will move to the primary monitor.

Is there a way to **keep windows/programs stay on their current positions** when turning off one of the monitors?

I searched google but couldn't find anything, most of the solutions are ****Windows key + P** but it doesn't work** as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good and old question, which is now almost no longer asked. Because there is **no real solution** to the problem.
You can see the following discussion traces:

[Anything to prevent apps from moving around monitors when unplugged?](https://superuser.com/questions/1579021/anything-to-prevent-apps-from-moving-around-monitors-when-unplugged)

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monitors/comments/nsuqsm/has_there_been_a_solution_to_the_monitor/

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-monitor-auto-detect/199c495f-3912-4d8e-bdd6-a3f455996a32

Even HDMI dummy display plugis proposed as a solution to this problem:
https://monitordetectkiller.com/ (and so on)

I have been trying to make a software solution to this issue for a long time, but a direct solution is not possible due to Windows PnP.